# Advance to GO, collect $400?

Tags: monopoly

I've recently come back to playing Monopoly, but one thing that's intrigued me is the following card, in the Chance pile.

[image]

The wording says "Advance to go (Collect $200)".  Modern versions, like the one I have in my home, are "Advance to GO, Collect $200".

My question is, what exactly does it mean, when it says "Collect $200"?  Since there's also a message on the GO tile, stating "As you pass GO, collect $200", does this mean if I draw the card above, I can collect $400 in one go? $200 from what the card says, and another $200 from the board?

Comment: The parentheses are essential.  They mean "Advance to Go (and collect $200 as you normally would)."  I think they're intended to remove the ambiguity where you advance past Go and land on Chance in one turn, and you draw the above Chance card.  In *that* case, you would get $400: $200 for advancing past Go before landing on Chance, and $200 for advancing to Go with the Chance card.  But on your next turn, moving past Go, you wouldn't get *another* $200.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you only collect $200 dollars, not $400. From [the official rules](http://richard_wilding.tripod.com/monorules.htm):

> Each time a player's token lands on or passes over GO, whether by
>   throwing the dice or drawing a card, the Banker pays that player a
>   $200 salary. The $200 is paid only once each time around the board.

You only land on GO once, so you only get one payout. The message on the card is just to remind you that landing on GO also pays out.

However, there's nothing stopping you playing this variant as a [house rule](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Monopoly/House_Rules#Go_and_movement), which is not uncommon:

> According to the official rules each player receives $200 for passing
>   Go. However, due to the Chance and Community Chest cards which
>   instruct players to Advance to Go and Collect $200 - A popular house
>   rule is that you collect $200 for landing on Go plus $200 for actually
>   passing Go. Therefore, it is common to pay someone $400 for landing
>   directly on Go: $200 for actually landing on Go plus the $200 as an
>   advance for their next move when they literally pass Go.

Comment: While nothing prevents you from having a house rule of a double Go payout for landing on Go, or from other house rules that increase the amount of money in the game, these house rules are responsible for Monopoly's reputation as a game that takes hours to play.  The game is designed to siphon off money as it goes.  That's what keeps it short.  Try the game a few times *without* these house rules and you'll find it can be finished in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

In monopoly there are two kinds of cards that move you around the board.  Ones are that keep moving you clockwise until you hit the set square.  This is one of them.  On those cards it says to collect 200 if you pass go.  In this case you are landing on it directly.

The other types of cards move you directly to a square.  This may be the only one but it makes the point. "Go directly to jail, do not pass go do not collect $200"
[image: Go o jail]

So to answer your question, the reason that text is on the card is just to differentiate it from the go to jail card